# Iphone 5s Activation no Sim card installed?

Tags: ios

hi i buy iphone 5s in uk but my mobile not Activate. That error is saying no sim card installed. now I'm in India i don't have sim card how to activate my Iphone. That Iphone not asking Apple ID.

Comment: You need a SIM card to activate your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You need a SIM card to activate an iPhone.